# Cosine scoring in whoosh, python

Tags: python, whoosh

I've implemented some python code to run search on whoosh using BM25 and all went out ok, but now that I'm trying to change scoring mechanism to Cosine, I'm getting this error:

> File "TFIDF.py", line 18, in tfidf
>       with ix.searcher(weighting=whoosh.scoring.Cosine()) as searcher: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cosine'

If I import Cosine

```
from whoosh.scoring import Cosine
```

I get this:

```
File "TFIDF.py", line 4, in <module>
    from whoosh.scoring import Cosine
ImportError: cannot import name Cosine
```

My code is below:

```
import whoosh
from whoosh.scoring import Cosine
from whoosh.fields import *
from whoosh.scoring import *
from whoosh.qparser import *
from whoosh.query import *
from whoosh.index import open_dir

#Index path
lab3dir= "../lab3/Aula3_1/"
ix = open_dir(lab3dir + "indexdir") #Index generated in previous lab


def cosine(queryTerms):
    list=[]
    dict={} # dict com ID do doc e Similiaridade 
    with ix.searcher(weighting=whoosh.scoring.Cosine()) as searcher:
        query = QueryParser("content", ix.schema, group=OrGroup).parse(u(queryTerms))
        results = searcher.search(query, limit=100)
        for i,r in enumerate(results):
            list.append(r["id"])
            print r, results.score(i)
            dict[r["id"]]= results.score(i)
    return dict
```

Any ideias???

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a way to do cosine scoring in Whoosh?

Comment: Yes, but honestly I'm not remembering totally what was the catch, but you can find the code of it working here: https://github.com/diasdavid/eadw-ist/blob/master/src/newsSearch/TFIDF.py

if I'm not wrong TFIDF===cosine

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I don't see the cosine scoring formula in your code or in Whoosh's TF_IDF implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on http://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/searching.html#the-searcher-object, which I assume is what you're looking at is incorrect as you have found. Look at the documentation (http://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/api/scoring.html#module-whoosh.scoring) or the source code (https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/src/362fc2999c8cabc51370f433de7402fafd536ec6/src/whoosh/scoring.py?at=default) for the options actually available.